# Nginx configuration errors

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am having some problems to configure a nginx reverse proxy with some url.
My configuration is:

```
events {
      worker_connections 768;
}

http {
     include       mime.types;
     default_type  application/octet-stream;

     sendfile        on;
     keepalive_timeout  65;
     access_log /dev/stdout combined;
     error_log /dev/stdout warn;

  server {
    ssl_certificate        /opt/ssl/ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /opt/ssl/ca.key;
    listen 443 ssl;

location /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/prometheuslb/proxy/ {
          resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
          set $endpoint "http://prometheuslb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:9090/";
          proxy_pass $endpoint;
        }

        location /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy/ {
          resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
          set $endpoint "http://pushgatewaylb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:9091/";
          proxy_pass $endpoint;
        }

        location /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/cratedb/proxy/ {
          resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
          set $endpoint "http://cratedb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:4200/";
          proxy_pass $endpoint;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
}
```

- For the Prometheus url I have an **infinite loop** so the page doesnt load.
- For Pushgateway it redirects wrong, becuase it should look for styles in /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy/ but it dismisses that url part, for example it should look for styles in /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy/static/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
- And for cratedb I receive this error: **Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html**

I can modify the existing server block, but I cannot create a separate server block.

I tested pinging targets and they work ok, also if I dont use varibles they work ok, but I need to use variables with resolver becuase we need nginx start ok even though endpoints are not available.

How can I fix these errors?
Thank you.

**Edit1:**

Thank you very much @Richard Smith for the response, I am not expert in nginx and help is very appreciated:
The new config:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/prometheuslb/proxy(/.*)$ {
          resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
          set $endpoint "http://prometheuslb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:9090";
          proxy_pass $endpoint$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy(/.*)$ {
          resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
          set $endpoint "http://pushgatewaylb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:9091";
          proxy_pass $endpoint$1;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/cratedb/proxy(/.*)$ {
          resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
          set $endpoint "http://cratedb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:4200";
          proxy_pass $endpoint$1;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
```

fixed the cratedb style error and Prometheus infinite loop.

Now I have other errors in prometheus in inspect of browser says GET https://domain/api/v1/namespaces/clautagsfed/services/prometheuslb/proxy/api/v1/query?query=time()&_=1541522597396 400 (Bad Request) ,

so seems there is something missing in config yet (without variables it works ok).

And regarding Pushgateway the same problem as explained above that it should look style in /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy/static/jquery-2.1.4.min.js but it looks in jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a variable the behaviour of the `proxy_pass` directive changes. Basically, if you specify a URI, the full URI needs to be specified. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

- Remove the trailing `/` from your `$endpoint` variable
- Either translate the URI using a `rewrite...break` statement, or convert your locations to *regular expressions* and use a capture

For example:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/prometheuslb/proxy(/.*)$ {
    resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
    set $endpoint "http://prometheuslb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:9090";
    proxy_pass $endpoint$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Richard Smith, that fixed a lot part of the problem I am not expert in nginx so that was very helpful. In another hand I still have other problems explained in the edit about.

Comment: I forgot to append the query string. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! the prometheus is all fixed. The only still having problems is the pushgateway, I tried adding the $is_args$args as well in pushgateway, but it is still looking styles without /api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy/   , any clue?

Comment: Does pushgateway work with `proxy_pass http://pushgatewaylb.mynamespace.svc.skydns.local:9091/;`?

Comment: I tried without variables and the same style error: location /api/v1/namespaces/clautagsfed/services/pushgatewaylb/proxy/ { proxy_pass http://pushgatewaylb.clautagsfed.svc.skydns.local:9091/;
        }